# FileSystem.getInfoAsync() crashes the app

Tags: react-native, file, expo, uri

I'm trying to develop an epub reader using react native and expo, and the following is the code used to prompt the user to select a file:

```
// method to pick a file from the file system from FileSystemHelper class
static async pickFile() {
    try {
        // prompt the user to pick files
        let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({ multiple: true })
        if (result.type === 'cancel') {
            // The user cancelled the file picker
            return;
        }

        return result
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Error while picking files: ", err)
    }
}
```

the code used to check if the file exists:

```
// method used to check if the file exists from the FileSystemHelper class
static async checkFileExists(uri) {
        try {
            // check if the file exists
            const fileExists = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(uri)
            if (!fileExists.exists) {
                console.log("File does not exist")
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("Error while checking if file exists: ", err)
        }
    }
```

and finally the code that's executed when the user presses the button to add a book:

```
// function to handle picking a file
  const handlePickFile = async () => {
    const result = await FileSystemHelper.pickFile()

    // decode the URI
    result.uri = decodeURI(result.uri)
    const URI = new URL(result.uri)

    // check that the file exists
    const fileExists = await FileSystemHelper.checkFileExists(URI)
    if (!fileExists) {
      console.log("File does not exist")
      return
    }
    
    // parse the result into a book object
    const info = await FileSystemHelper.extractInfo(URI)
  }
```

I've been having some problems reading the file after selecting it, so i decided to check if the URI is vali, but the app crashes the moment it reaches the `FileSystem.getInfoAsync()` call (it closes on my phone using expo go) and I have to restart the server and relog in.

for reference, console logging the URI of one example file prints out the following: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/30F628C2-C062-4449-B13B-B4EBE68CFC6F/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40omar4tw%2Finkwell/DocumentPicker/E15B6040-2929-41C2-83D6-B0AB4D9E1C34.epub/`

Any idea as to what may be the problem

Comment: can you show what the error is? thanks